# dice roller application with multiple classes

Tags: java, class

I am writing a program that rolls 2 dice and gives the user the option to repeat the roll (continue y/n).  Additionally the application needs to recognize when certain rolls are made like rolling a 7 or 2 (snake eyes)  im not sure if that needs to go in the main method or have its own class, im lost! please help.  below is what i have for the outline of what the application needs to be im not sure how to code it.

This is my first time writing my own classes to be used in a main method the layout is as follows:

```
public class DiceRollerApp
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    }// end main method
}// end App class

class Die
{
    public Die()
    {}           // default to six-sided die
    public Die(int sides)
    {}  // variable number of sides
    public void roll()
    {}     // randomly picks a face value
    public int getValue()
    {}  // returns the face value
}// end class Die

class PairOfDice
{
    public PairOfDice()
    {}          // default to six-sided dice
    public PairOfDice(int sides)
    {} // variable number of sides
    public void roll()
    {}         // roll both dice
    public int getValue1(){}       // get value of die1
    public int getValue2(){}       // get value of die2
    public int getSum()    {}
    // get sum of both dice
}// end class PairOfDice


public class Validator
{
    public static String getString(Scanner sc, String prompt)
    {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        String s = sc.next();  // read user entry
        sc.nextLine();  // discard any other data entered on the line
        return s;
    }

    public static int getInt(Scanner sc, String prompt)
    {
        int i = 0;
        boolean isValid = false;
        while (isValid == false)
        {
            System.out.print(prompt);
            if (sc.hasNextInt())
            {
                i = sc.nextInt();
                isValid = true;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Error! Invalid integer value. Try again.");
            }
            sc.nextLine();  // discard any other data entered on the line
        }
        return i;
    }

    public static int getInt(Scanner sc, String prompt,
    int min, int max)
    {
        int i = 0;
        boolean isValid = false;
        while (isValid == false)
        {
            i = getInt(sc, prompt);
            if (i <= min)
            System.out.println(
            "Error! Number must be greater than " + min + ".");
            else if (i >= max)
            System.out.println(
            "Error! Number must be less than " + max + ".");
            else
            isValid = true;
        }
        return i;
    }

    public static double getDouble(Scanner sc, String prompt)
    {
        double d = 0;
        boolean isValid = false;
        while (isValid == false)
        {
            System.out.print(prompt);
            if (sc.hasNextDouble())
            {
                d = sc.nextDouble();
                isValid = true;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Error! Invalid decimal value. Try again.");
            }
            sc.nextLine();  // discard any other data entered on the line
        }
        return d;
    }

    public static double getDouble(Scanner sc, String prompt,
    double min, double max)
    {
        double d = 0;
        boolean isValid = false;
        while (isValid == false)
        {
            d = getDouble(sc, prompt);
            if (d <= min)
            System.out.println(
            "Error! Number must be greater than " + min + ".");
            else if (d >= max)
            System.out.println(
            "Error! Number must be less than " + max + ".");
            else
            isValid = true;
        }
        return d;
    }
} // end class Validator
```

I have written the validator class already but did not post it here, its purpose is to simply validate the string from the question "Continue? y/n: "

im not sure how to code the die class and the pair of dice class, and i dont know  if i need to have a separate class for the DiceRollerApp.

Comment: There have been several questions identical to this one in the last couple of hours. Clearly an assignment has gone out and many students are too lazy to do any work themselves. Go away, attempt a solution, and come back only if you encounter a problem you can not figure out. Coming here and asking people to do your work for you is bad for you and bad for this site.

Comment: i didnt ask anyone to do my work, i asked about coding the die class, i have done my research and written several versions that did not work.  this is my last resort i dont want people to do my work, whats the point in that i wont learn anything.

Comment: Where's your code then? You've copy pasted the code skeleton provided to you. In other words you've done nothing. These kinds of "do my work for me" questions are not welcome here, that's why we all voted to close it. Make your questions aharp, narrow in scope - ideally at the level of one or two lines of code, then you'll get plenty of good help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Die 
{
    private int sides;

    private int value;

    public Die() {
        this.sides = 6;
    }           // default to six-sided die

    public Die(int sides) {
        this.sides = sides;
    }  // variable number of sides

    public void roll() {
        value = (int)(Math.random() * (sides-1)) + 1;
    }     // randomly picks a face value

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }  // returns the face value

}// end class Die
```